# "Undefined variable" error, when rendering data in a view

Tags: php, view, yii2

I want to render static array in `_form.php` view, using `actionCreate` method in Yii2. Here is my code:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
     return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
} else {
    $data = array('1'=>'AA','2'=>'BB');

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'data' => $data ,
    ]);
}
```

When I try to display this data in `_form.php` view, I am getting an error "*Undefined variable: data*".

Here is my `_form.php` code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'fixer_type[]')->dropDownList($data,['prompt'=>'Select Fixer Trade']) ?>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the `$data` to `create.php`.Render the same from your `create.php` to make it available in your `form.php`.

In your `create.php`

```
<?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
    'data' => $data ,
]) ?>
```